# How to calculate the operator norm $A:L^2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, adjoint-operators

For any $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we define $A: L^2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$ by $A(f)(x)=f(|x|)$. How to calculate the operator norm of $A$ and what is the adjoint of $A$?

Comment: any thoughts on your problem?

Comment: The user **copper.hat**'s answer shows how to determine the norm of $A$. For the adjoint, note: \begin{align*}
\langle Af, g \rangle
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \overline{f(|x|)} g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \overline{f(x)} g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{0}^{\infty} \overline{f(x)} g(-x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \overline{f(x)} (g(x)+g(-x))\mathbf{1}_{(0,\infty)}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Comment: @SangchulLee: Thanks, I forgot about the adjoint! I just added the answer as a comment since it was complete & I don't have time now.

Comment: You have $\|Af\|^2 = 2 \int_0^\infty f(x)^2 dx \le 2 \|f\|^2$.
This suggests a norm, and also how it might be obtained.

Comment: @copper.hat The operator norm is $\sqrt{2}$? I think it is $\sqrt{2}$ in the case when $L^2([0,1])$ but I am not sure about the case when $L^2(\mathbb{R}).$

Comment: @SangchulLee I am sorry but could you give me more hints? I need some more details why your hints suggests the adjoint of $A$. Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @SangchulLee Is the adjoint operator $A^\ast(g)(x)=g(x)+g(-x)$?

Comment: @aloevera: I am sure. My comment shows how. Why the doubt, I am not depending on a domain of $[0,1]$.